Intellij IDEA: how to use incompatible plugin / I18n Ally for Vue I18n
I've used the plugin I18n Ally which seems to be the only well working plugin for a Vue i18n integration in IntellijIDEA.
However, the latest versions of IntelliJ don't let me install i18n Ally, because it's "incompatible". Can I still use the plugin?

This Intellij IDEA issue tells that you can change the property idea.plugins.compatible.build. Follow these steps:

Find the compatible build number of your plugin, go to the Versions tab on the plugin homepage (this link for i18n Ally), click on the latest version and find the Compatibility Range. Copy the build number there (start of range, currently 232.9559 for i18n Ally).
In Intellij search for Registry in the "Search all" searchbox (press 2x Shift on keyboard)
search for property idea.plugins.compatible.build and paste your build number from step (1)
restart IntelliJ idea, go to Settings -> Plugins and search for your plugin. It now should be listed and installable.

Of course this can cause problems if the plugins are really incompatible. However, "i18n Ally" is working fine for me with Intellij IDEA 2024.1.1.
Attention: this could result in using wrong other plugins and making Intellij IDEA unstable, see this issue on YouTrack
